# Office 365 - Configuring Shared Mailbox

Tags: microsoft-office, exchange, office365

I'm trying to configure a shared mailbox for my company with Office 365. I've followed the docs as outlined here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-shared-mailboxes-in-Office-365-871a246d-3acd-4bba-948e-5de8be0544c9. However, I tried to send an email to the shared mailbox, but none of my members received the email.

[image]

Also, another thing I noticed that when I create a shared mailbox, a user has been added automatically to the list of Active Users, which got me thinking, is this new user need to have a license? Are there any additional configurations I need to do to get the Shared Mailbox feature up and running properly?

In case you're wondering if the DNS stuff such as MX, SRV, TEXT, and CNAME entries are correct, I think they already have, since I can properly login from my mobile devices, Mac, Windows PC as well as receiving and sending emails through each of the personal emails.

Or perhaps, do the shared mailboxes need 24 hours to take effect? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, if you send a mail to the shared mailbox, the users of that mailbox won’t get that e-mail in their own personal mailbox. Adding members to a shared mailbox means that, they can view the contents of the shared mailbox. For viewing contents in your shared mailbox from Outlook Web App,

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-and-use-a-shared-mailbox-in-Outlook-on-the-web-for-business-bc127866-42be-4de7-92ae-1ef2f787fd5c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

If you want users to receive the mails in their own personal mailbox, try configuring a distribution list instead of a shared mailbox.